# Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Tags: php

I've been reading every related question on SO, but I still don't understand where my error is.

On my wordpress site I have posts with a date that I need to display and I use this code:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20071005');
/*error here*/ $year = $date->format('Y');
echo $year;
```

The information are displayed correctly and my code seems to me coherently object-oriented style. Yet I can't get rid of this message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in 
/homez.763/frommeto/www/temp/wp-content/themes/fmty/page-listspace.php on line 23
```

Can you see if there's anything really wrong? Might it be something related to the version of php the server is running? I'm using PHP 5.4.1

**EDIT**

var_dump($date) returns

```
object(DateTime)#84 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2007-10-05 10:44:57"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

Comment: The code itself should work fine (see [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EJZXrS)). It must be a configuration issue.

Comment: your code, runs good in my pc.my php version is 5.4.16.try to set timezone in php.ini

Comment: If you add this `print_r(DateTime::getLastErrors());` just after `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20071005');` outputs any error?

Comment: I had the same issue, but I noticed the code get triggered more than once that caused the issue to get caught. Just put the code in a separate file and verify it whether works or not.

Comment: @SenG true, I ended up separating the calls in different files for other reasons and the problem disappeared, But I still don't know how to achieve multiple calls in the same document...

Answer (score 1):

I copied and pasted your code and it worked just fine. I am using `php5.4.11.`

If all you are doing is trying to display the year, as in your example, you could use the `strtotime()` and `date()`

```
$date = strtotime('20071005') ;
$year = date('Y', $date) ;
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
$year = date('Y',strtotime('20071005')) ;
```